# How to convert Multi-Index into a Heatmap

Tags: pandas, indexing, heatmap

New to Pandas/Python, I have managed to make an index like below;

```
MultiIndex([( 1,  1,  4324),
            ( 1,  2,  8000),
            ( 1,  3,  8545),
            ( 1,  4, 8544),
            ( 1,  5, 7542),
            (12, 30, 7854),
            (12, 31, 7511)],
            names=['month', 'day', 'count'], length=366)
```

I'm struggling to find out how I can store the first number into a list (the 1-12 one) the second number into another list (1-31 values) and the third number into another seperate list (scores 0-9000)

I am trying to build a heatmap that is Month x Day on the axis' and using count as the values and failing horribly! I am assuming I have to seperate Month, Day and Count into seperate lists to make the heat map?

```
data1 = pd.read_csv("a2data/Data1.csv")
data2 = pd.read_csv("a2data/Data2.csv")
merged_df = pd.concat([data1, data2])
merged_df.set_index(['month', 'day'], inplace=True)
merged_df.sort_index(inplace=True)
merged_df2=merged_df.groupby(['month', 'day']).count.mean().reset_index()
merged_df2.set_index(['month', 'day', 'count'], inplace=True)
```

#struggling here to seperate out month, day and count in order to make a heatmap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for:

```
# let start here
merged_df2=merged_df.groupby(['month', 'day']).count.mean()

# use sns
import seaborn as sns
sns.heatmap(merged_df2.unstack('day'))
```

Output:

[image]

Or you can use `plt`:

```
merged_df2=merged_df.groupby(['month', 'day']).count.mean().unstack('day')

plt.imshow(merged_df2)
plt.xticks(np.arange(merged_df2.shape[1]), merged_df2.columns)
plt.yticks(np.arange(merged_df2.shape[0]), merged_df2.index)
plt.show()
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your contribution Quang, in theory yes thats exactly what I am after.

Unfortunately I've been specifically told I can't utilise the seaborn sns heatmap, is there an alternative way to reach what you've done here?

Appreciate your help!

Comment: @Valador1988 I don't get the message in my system. Probably a update of matplotlib helps.

Comment: EDIT: Sorry for edit - I originally put your code in incorrectly! Now I receive the below message!

Thanks for this Quang - I don't know if I slotted in your code correctly, I receive the following error message;

KeyError: "None of ['month', 'day', 'count'] are in the columns"


EDIT 2: Sorry realised if I removed the merged_df2.set_index(['month', 'date_of_month', 'births'], inplace=True) statement your code now works!